# Angular: div with contenteditable by double click or type anykey

Tags: javascript, angular

**THE QUESTION**

I want make a component with a editable area. The editing is enabled in two way:

1. User first click on the area and type something
2. User doubleclick on the area

both feature doesn't works as expected.

In the first case, the area become editable after the click, but if press a key the content become empty but without the key/character. The code:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
onWindowKeydown($event) {
  // ... other code
  // empty the content
  this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML = ''; // works
  // set the focus
  this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.focus(); // works
  // re-dispatch the keydown event for inser the character pressed
  this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.dispatchEvent($event); // doesn't works!
}
```

In the  second case, after the double-click the component become editable, but but if press a key the content doesn't update. The code:

```
onDblClick($event) {
  // ... othe code
  this.allowEdit = true;
}
```

how fix it?

**WORKING DEMO**

see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwxmv2

**FULL CODE**

*app.component.ts*

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  AfterContentInit,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  SimpleChange,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('contentWrapper') contentWrapper: ElementRef;

  private allowEdit: boolean;
  private isSelected: boolean;
  private editable: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.allowEdit = false;
    this.isSelected = false;
    this.editable = true;
  }

  onClick($event) {
    this.isSelected = true;
  }

  onDblClick($event) {
    this.isSelected = true;
    if ( this.editable ) {
      this.allowEdit = true;
    }
  }

  onBlur($event) {
    this.isSelected = false;
    if ( this.editable ) {
      this.allowEdit = false;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  onWindowKeydown($event) {
    // if component is selected...
    if ( this.isSelected ) {
      // and is editable...
      if ( this.editable ) {
        // and edit is  allowed...
        if ( !this.allowEdit ) {

          this.allowEdit = true;

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';
            this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.focus();
            this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.dispatchEvent($event);
          }, 5);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  styleObject(): Object {
    if ( this.isSelected ) {
        return {
          borderColor: 'red',
          borderStyle: 'dashed',
          borderWidth: '2px'
        };
    }
    return {
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      borderStyle: 'dashed',
      borderWidth: '2px'
    };
  }
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div class="warapper">
    <div class="editable" [ngStyle]="styleObject()" [attr.contenteditable]="allowEdit" (click)="onClick($event)" (dblclick)="onDblClick($event)" (blur)="onBlur($event)" #contentWrapper>
        Click here for select and press any key or double click here for edit this content
    </div>
</div>
```

*app.component.css*

```
.warapper .editable { 
    border: 'none'; 
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    min-height: 15px;
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I see what you are talking about, but after a double click, if I click on the text again then I can edit fine. It needs that extra click to actual put the cursor in the text to start typing. I don't think it's the wrong functionality because double click sets it to be editable, so from then on you can click into the box and edit the text.

Comment: i want the cursor ready for typing after dobuble-click, like "office excel cell"

Comment: If you remove the single click and change the double click method to fire on a single click, then a double click will set the thing to editable on the first click, and on second click put the cursor in the box.